# Woocommerce Smart Coupons - remove_action() not working

Tags: php, woocommerce

The woocommerce smart coupons plugin generates a coupon in the `woocommerce_email_after_order_table`. I'd like to remove this from the order emails. To me it looks like a straight forward action, but it's not working. This is the action from the plugin.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_SC_Display_Coupons' ) ) {
    class WC_SC_Display_Coupons {
        private static $instance = null;
        public static $endpoint;
        private function __construct() {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $this, 'generated_coupon_details_after_order_table' ), 10, 3 );
        }
```

This is what I have tried in functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( 'WC_SC_Display_Coupons', 'generated_coupon_details_after_order_table' ), 10, 3 );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $GLOBALS['WC_SC_Display_Coupons'], 'generated_coupon_details_after_order_table' ), 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Where do you add it?

Comment: @m4n0 functions.php

Comment: I guess the add_action is limited to the class. So you might want to access the function inside the class using `WC_SC_Display_Coupons()->`. I can only give you a hint. You can also make the class available globally. More info here: https://mekshq.com/remove-wordpress-action-filter-class/

Comment: @m4n0I have tried the $GLOBALS inside the action as well to set `global $WC_SC_Display_Coupons;`. I have updated this in the question.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/311686/70936

Comment: @m4n0 I am not able to produce the option to initiate the class into a variable. It gives me an `invalid context error for private WC_SC_Display_Coupons`